# OpenCV C++ How to write a function which does the same Matlab's bwareaopen function?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm trying to convert bwareaopen function to OpenCV C++ ... 
I Found this code but it is not working correctly.

So if anyone have solved this problem and can help me, I would be really delighted.

```
void removeSmallBlobs(cv::Mat& im, double size)
{
    // Only accept CV_8UC1
    if (im.channels() != 1 || im.type() != CV_8U)
        return;

    // Find all contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(im.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        // Calculate contour area
        double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);

        // Remove small objects by drawing the contour with black color
        if (area > 0 && area <= size)
            cv::drawContours(im, contours, i, CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by it is not working? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What size number I give input there are always a lot of small blobs.

Comment: Are there any errors or just nothing happens after the execution?

Comment: no not errors. Code compiles fine but the result is not satisfying

Comment: @user3499689 - That code works fine.  I've used it several times in the past.  Please give an example image and example input parameters into this function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need opening morphological operation. [Here you can see an example](http://qtandopencv.blogspot.ru/2013/09/morphological-operations-and-opencv2-01.html).

Or take a look here: [How to filter small segments from image in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732431/solved-how-to-filter-small-segments-from-image-in-opencv?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I am using cvBlobsLib to implement such function in opencv. You should first compile and include the cvBlobsLib in your project. The library link is here:[cvBlobsLib](http://opencvblobslib.github.io/opencvblobslib/)

Because matlab canny function does the Gaussian blur by default but opencv doesn't, you should first Gaussian blur the image to reduce noise. Then you dectect the canny edge, then you delete the edges that is shorter or longer than a given length measured by pixel.

Here is my code.

```
#include <highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "BlobResult.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void bwareaopen( Mat& img, int size);

 int main()
 {
     Mat img;
     img = imread("1.jpg");

     Mat gray;
     cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);


     GaussianBlur( gray, gray, Size(7, 7), 2, 2);
     Mat edges;
     Canny(gray,edges,50,500,5,true);
     imshow("raw edge",edges);
     bwareaopen( edges, 800);
     imshow("edge",edges);
     waitKey(0);


 }

 void bwareaopen( Mat& img, int size)
 {
     CBlobResult blobs;
     blobs = CBlobResult( img ,Mat(),4);
     blobs.Filter( blobs, B_INCLUDE, CBlobGetLength(), B_GREATER, size );

     Mat newimg(img.size(),img.type());
     newimg.setTo(0);
     for(int i=0;i<blobs.GetNumBlobs();i++)
     {
         blobs.GetBlob(i)->FillBlob(newimg,CV_RGB(255,255,255),0,0,true);
     }
     img = newimg;
 }
```

Comment: Where is the header definition file: `BlobsResult.h`?

Comment: Update your post with this information.  BTW, I have a few comments for you: (1) `bwareaopen` does **not** perform a Gaussian blur by default.  There is no blurring done whatsoever.  The function removes filled in contours whose areas are below a certain amount.  There's no need to blur in this case whatsoever. (2) `bwareaopen` operates on objects whose areas are filled.  Doing an edge detection will not perform well because the total area for a shape is defined as the sum of all pixels that are white that belong to a single object. Doing an edge detection will only give you the perimeter.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I mean matlab canny does the Gausssian blur but opencv doesn't.

Comment: OK.  You should probably correct your post to reflect that MATLAB performs Gaussian blurring on the Canny edge detector, not `bwareaopen`.  In that case, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I changed the line

`if (area > 0 && area <= size)` to

```
if (area <= size)
```

This is after I found that many small blobs had area 0. That worked for me.